# How to prioritise waiting CompletableFutures by access time instead of creation time?

Tags: java, performance, asynchronous, priority-queue, completable-future

TL;DR: *When several `CompletableFuture`s are waiting to get executed, how can I **prioritize** those whose values i'm **interested in**?*

I have a list of 10,000 `CompletableFuture`s (which calculate the data rows for an internal report over the product database):

```
List<Product> products = ...;

List<CompletableFuture<DataRow>> dataRows = products
    .stream()
    .map(p -> CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> calculateDataRowForProduct(p), singleThreadedExecutor))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Each takes around **50ms** to complete, so the entire thing finishes in **500sec**. (they all share the same DB connection, so cannot run in parallel).

Let's say I want to access the data row of the 9000th product:
`dataRows.get(9000).join()`

The problem is, all these CompletableFutures are executed in the order they have been **created**, not in the order they are **accessed**. Which means I have to wait **450sec** for it to calculate stuff that at the moment I don't care about, to finally get to the data row I want.

**Question**:
Is there any way to change this behaviour, so that the Futures I try to **access** get **priority** over those I don't care about at the moment?

**First thoughts**:

I noticed that a `ThreadPoolExecutor` uses a `BlockingQueue<Runnable>` to queue up entries waiting for an available Thread.

So I thought about using a `PriorityBlockingQueue`, to change the priority of the `Runnable` when I access its `CompletableFuture` but:

- `PriorityBlockingQueue` does not have a method to *reprioritize* an existing element, and
- I need to figure out a way to get from the `CompletableFuture` to the corresponding `Runnable` entry in the queue.

Before I go further down this road, do you think this sounds like the correct approach. Do others ever had this kind of requirement? I tried to search for it, but found exactly nothing. Maybe `CompletableFuture` is not the correct way of doing this?

**Background**:
We have an internal report which displays 100 products per page. Initially we precalculated all DataRows for the report, which took way to long if someone has that many products.

So first optimization was to wrap the calculation in a memoized supplier:

```
List<Supplier<DataRow>> dataRows = products
    .stream()
    .map(p -> Suppliers.memoize(() -> calculateDataRowForProduct(p)))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

This means that initial display of first 100 entries now takes **5sec** instead of 500sec (which is great), but when the user switches to the next pages, it takes **another 5sec** for each single one of them.

So the idea is, while the user is staring at the first screen, why not precalculate the next pages in the background. Which leads me to my question above.

Comment: May I ask what is a DataRow? Also, are you using plain java or you happen to also have framework support?

Comment: @EiriniGraonidou DataRow is just some result value of the Supplier (which will get displayed in the report, whatever that is). I use WebObjects as a framework, but I don't think that's relevant to the question. :)

Answer (score 6):

Interesting problem :)

One way is to roll out custom `FutureTask` class to facilitate changing priorities of tasks dynamically.

`DataRow` and `Product` are both taken as just `String` here for simplicity.

```java
import java.util.*;
import java.util.concurrent.*;

public class Testing {
    private static String calculateDataRowForProduct(String product) {
        try {
            // Dummy operation.
            Thread.sleep(200);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("Computation done for " + product);
        return "data row for " + product;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException {
        PriorityBlockingQueue<Runnable> customQueue = new PriorityBlockingQueue<Runnable>(1, new CustomRunnableComparator());
        ThreadPoolExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolExecutor(1, 1, 0L, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS, customQueue);
        List<String> products = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            products.add("product" + i);
        }
        Map<Integer, PrioritizedFutureTask<String>> taskIndexMap = new HashMap<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < products.size(); i++) {
            String product = products.get(i);
            Callable callable = () -> calculateDataRowForProduct(product);
            PrioritizedFutureTask<String> dataRowFutureTask = new PrioritizedFutureTask<>(callable, i);
            taskIndexMap.put(i, dataRowFutureTask);
            executor.execute(dataRowFutureTask);
        }

        List<Integer> accessOrder = new ArrayList<>();
        accessOrder.add(4);
        accessOrder.add(7);
        accessOrder.add(2);
        accessOrder.add(9);
        int priority = -1 * accessOrder.size();
        for (Integer nextIndex : accessOrder) {
            PrioritizedFutureTask taskAtIndex = taskIndexMap.get(nextIndex);
            assert (customQueue.remove(taskAtIndex));
            customQueue.offer(taskAtIndex.set_priority(priority++));
            // Now this task will be at the front of the thread pool queue.
            // Hence this task will execute next.
        }
        for (Integer nextIndex : accessOrder) {
            PrioritizedFutureTask<String> dataRowFutureTask = taskIndexMap.get(nextIndex);
            String dataRow = dataRowFutureTask.get();
            System.out.println("Data row for index " + nextIndex + " = " + dataRow);
        }
    }
}

class PrioritizedFutureTask<T> extends FutureTask<T> implements Comparable<PrioritizedFutureTask<T>> {

    private Integer _priority = 0;
    private Callable<T> callable;

    public PrioritizedFutureTask(Callable<T> callable, Integer priority) {
        super(callable);
        this.callable = callable;
        _priority = priority;
    }

    public Integer get_priority() {
        return _priority;
    }

    public PrioritizedFutureTask set_priority(Integer priority) {
        _priority = priority;
        return this;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(@NotNull PrioritizedFutureTask<T> other) {
        if (other == null) {
            throw new NullPointerException();
        }
        return get_priority().compareTo(other.get_priority());
    }
}

class CustomRunnableComparator implements Comparator<Runnable> {
    @Override
    public int compare(Runnable task1, Runnable task2) {
        return ((PrioritizedFutureTask)task1).compareTo((PrioritizedFutureTask)task2);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Computation done for product0
Computation done for product4
Data row for index 4 = data row for product4
Computation done for product7
Data row for index 7 = data row for product7
Computation done for product2
Data row for index 2 = data row for product2
Computation done for product9
Data row for index 9 = data row for product9
Computation done for product1
Computation done for product3
Computation done for product5
Computation done for product6
Computation done for product8
```

There is one more scope of optimization here.
The `customQueue.remove(taskAtIndex)` operation has `O(n)` time complexity with respect to the size of the queue (or the total number of products).
It might not affect much if the number of products is less (<= 10^5).
But it might result in a performance issue otherwise.

One solution to that is to extend `BlockingPriorityQueue` and roll out functionality to remove an element from a priority queue in `O(logn)` rather than O(n).
We can achieve that by keeping a hashmap inside the PriorityQueue structure. This hashmap will keep a count of elements vs the index (or indices in case of duplicates) of that element in the underlying array.
Fortunately, I had already implemented such a heap in [Python](https://github.com/Anmol-Singh-Jaggi/interview-notes/blob/master/notes/algo-ds-practice/ds/heap/heap.py) sometime back.
If you have more questions on this optimization, its probably better to ask a new question altogether.

Comment: Wow, a complete implementation, when I only asked if I'm heading in the right direction. Thanks a lot!
This is basically what I envisioned, except using `FutureTask` instead of `CompletedFuture`. I didn't know about the `ThreadPoolExecutor.submit()` problem (and not sure I understand it or the solution).
The only thing I would need to add, as I do not know the access order before hand, the repriorization would have to happen in the `FutureTask.get()` method.

Comment: Its ok if you dont know the access order beforehand. Lets say you want to access 90th element. Then just execute these lines before trying to do `get()` on that future task: 
  `PrioritizedFutureTask task = taskIndexMap.get(90);
  assert (customQueue.remove(task));
  int topElementPriority = ((PrioritizedFutureTask)customQueue.peek()).getPriority();
  customQueue.offer(task.set_priority(topElementPriority-1));`

Comment: Basically, whatever task has the lowest priority, that will execute first (sounds a bit counterintuitive I know). So we would want to change the priority of our desired task to the lowest in the queue.

Comment: Side question, why are you writing `"product" + Integer.valueOf(i).toString()` instead of just `"product" + i`?

Comment: Damn I got confused between how string concatenation works between Python and Java. In Python, string + int will result in error.

Comment: I didn't realize that about `execute`. Thanks for pointing that out @Holger. Have updated the answer.

Answer (score 3):

You could avoid submitting all of the tasks to the executor at the start, instead only submit one background task and when it finishes submit the next. If you want to get the 9000th row submit it immediately (if it has not already been submitted):

```
static class FutureDataRow {
    CompletableFuture<DataRow> future;
    int index;
    List<FutureDataRow> list;
    Product product;
    
    FutureDataRow(List<FutureDataRow> list, Product product){
        this.list = list;
        index = list.size();
        list.add(this);
        this.product = product;
    }
    public DataRow get(){
        submit();
        return future.join();
    }
    private synchronized void submit(){
        if(future == null) future = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> 
            calculateDataRowForProduct(product), singleThreadedExecutor);
    }
    private void background(){
        submit();
        if(index >= list.size() - 1) return;
        future.whenComplete((dr, t) -> list.get(index + 1).background());
    }
}

...

    List<FutureDataRow> dataRows = new ArrayList<>();
    products.forEach(p -> new FutureDataRow(dataRows, p));
    dataRows.get(0).background();
```

If you want you could also submit the next row inside the get method if you expect that they will navigate to the next page afterwards.

---

If you were instead using a multithreaded executor and you wanted to run multiple background tasks concurrently you could modify the background method to find the next unsubmitted task in the list and start it when the current background task has finished.

```
    private synchronized boolean background(){
        if(future != null) return false;
        submit();
        future.whenComplete((dr, t) -> {
            for(int i = index + 1; i < list.size(); i++){
                if(list.get(i).background()) return;
            }
        });
        return true;
    }
```

You would also need to start the first n tasks in the background instead of just the first one.

```
    int n = 8; //number of active background tasks
    for(int i = 0; i < dataRows.size() && n > 0; i++){
        if(dataRows.get(i).background()) n--;
    }
```

Comment: Loved the creativity here! BTW how would you solve this problem if the thread pool had multiple threads and tasks were able to run in parallel.

Comment: @AnmolSinghJaggi I updated the answer with a solution for a multithreaded executor.

Comment: Thanks. But if you execute background on the first FutureDataRow, it will submit all the tasks at that moment itself. So now if I want to access 9000th element, it will still take 450s. How does it solve the OP's problem? Sorry if I am missing something.

Comment: @AnmolSinghJaggi I don't know why you think it will submit all the tasks at that moment, background only ever submits zero or one tasks, and when the submitted task finishes it finds the next unstarted one to submit.

Comment: I was talking about your second multi thread pool solution. Yes you are right. Sorry I had misunderstood the solution. It will only start the next closest unstarted future task.

Comment: But if we want to fully utilise the thread-pool, then we will need to know the size of the thread pool beforehand and start as many tasks initially, as you rightly mentioned at the end. One consequence of this is that when you want to run the 9000th task, it will have to wait for those 8 tasks to finish first. And the next time when we want, say, 8000th task, it will have to wait for 9 tasks to finish. So the more times we request for a random index to start, the more it will have to wait. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @AnmolSinghJaggi If the pool has 8 threads and we request the 9000th task it will only need to wait for one of the threads to finish its task, not all 8. After the first thread finishes, a background task will be queued behind all of the requested tasks. If you then request another index, that will be queued behind the pending background task.

Comment: Oh yes you are right. Essentially, the queue will always almost be empty. As soon as a new Task is submitted, it will run instantly when one of 8 threads are free. Silly me!

Comment: I would say this solution is better than mine.

Comment: Interesting out-of-the-box thinking. So you basically implemented a little scheduler yourself. What I don't really like about this idea, that I would have to start it up manually, so when more values arrive later, I would need to check every time if the whole thing is still running, and if not start it up again. I could of course wrap it into a little Scheduler class which takes care of that, but then I would have reimplemented something that the existing Executor class already does.

Comment: Anyway, I have now solved my real problem (albeit not the question I asked) some completely different way. Thanks a lot for the interesting ideas.

Answer (score 3):

To answer my own question...

There is a surprisingly **simple** (and surprisingly **boring**) solution to my problem. I have no idea why it took me three days to find it, I guess it required the right mindset, that you only have when walking along an endless tranquilizing beach looking into the sunset on a quiet Sunday evening.

So, ah, it's a little bit embarrassing to write this, but when I need to fetch a certain value (say for 9000th product), and the *future* has **not** yet computed that value, I can, instead of somehow forcing the *future* to produce that value asap (by doing all this repriorisation and scheduling magic), I can, well, I can, ... simply ... **compute that value myself**! Yes! Wait, what? Seriously, that's it?

It's something like this: `if (!future.isDone()) {future.complete(supplier.get());}`

I just need to store the original `Supplier` alongside the `CompletableFuture` in some wrapper class. This is the wrapper class, which works like a charm, all it needs is a better name:

```
public static class FuturizedMemoizedSupplier<T> implements Supplier<T> {
    private CompletableFuture<T> future;
    private Supplier<T> supplier;

    public FuturizedSupplier(Supplier<T> supplier) {
        this.supplier = supplier;
        this.future = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(supplier, singleThreadExecutor);
    }

    public T get() {
        // if the future is not yet completed, we just calculate the value ourselves, and set it into the future
        if (!future.isDone()) {
            future.complete(supplier.get());
        }
        supplier = null;
        return future.join();
    }
}
```

Now, I think, there is a small chance for a race condition here, which could lead to the `supplier` being executed twice. But actually, I don't care, it produces the same value anyway.

**Afterthoughts**:
I have no idea why I didn't think of this earlier, I was completely fixated on the idea, it has to be the `CompletableFuture` which calculates the value, and it has to run in one of these background threads, and whatnot, and, well, none of these mattered or were in any way a requirement.

I think this whole question is a classic example of *Ask what problem you really want to solve* instead of *coming up with a half baked broken solution, and ask how to fix that*. In the end, I didn't care about `CompletableFuture` or any of its features at all, it was just the easiest way that came to my mind to run something in the background.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Great idea. However, note that if you do this, then it essentially becomes a 2 threaded thread-pool. Your main thread has become another thread that is computing the futures. I hope the internal db connection is being shared in a thread-safe way.

Comment: Yes, exactly, each thread locks the db connection, when it calculates a value. That was actually the reason how I came up with this solution, because the main-thread also holds the db-lock, and I got a deadlock when it wanted the value of a future that was not yet calculated. So I thought, Oh no, not only do I have to force the future to prioritize its calculation, I also have to force it to calculate it in my own thread (is that even possible?) Only then did it occur to me, what the heck, forget the future, I can just calculate the thing myself... Locking and priorization problem solved... :)